# Should I install Scala separately for command line and Eclipse IDE?

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

I've installed Scala IDE for Eclipse using the update mechanism, and then I found that there's no command line tools included there. So is it correct that I should download another copy of Scala package for the command line support and maintain both separately?

Or is there an integrated way to get it work in both environments? I just want to write and debug code in Eclipse and occasionally run it on the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can open a Scala command-line within Eclipse.  Just go to `Window` -> `Show View` -> `Scala Interpreter`, and it will open an interpreter window that has your project loaded into the classpath.

Second, there's nothing wrong with having a separate Scala installation for command-line use.  I do this.  It's often convenient to have a few terminal windows where you can run stuff or quickly test bits of code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the scala compiler first. Otherwise you can not use the eclipse plugin. If you have installed the scala compiler, you just need to add it to your classpath. Now you can type `scala` into any terminal you are using and the REPL starts.

Comment: False: the Scala-IDE plugin includes its own Scala compiler.  A separate installation is totally optional.

Comment: In this case I appologize for my wrong answer. When I installed the scala plugin for eclipse I read that you need it. That is the reason I wrote this answer.

Comment: @T.Grottker, your answer is false, but however knowing it is false provides a useful information